# Laravel validation rules for decimal

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-4

Wondering if it's possible to set rules for validating decimal with the format XX,XX ?
I have found that its possible with integer not decimal:

```
public static $rules = array(
        'T_Badende_per_Time' => 'integer');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could always use the `regex` rule to validate it's of a given format:

```
public static $rules = array(
    'T_Badende_per_Time' => 'regex:/[\d]{2},[\d]{2}/'
);
```

That will return true if you have 2 digits, followed by a comma, followed by another 2 digits.

Comment: That worked perfect, if I want to validate only by if its decimal, either be one or two digits before and after comma. Is this the right way: 'regex:/[\d]{0},[\d]{0}/');

Comment: If you want it to be one or two digits, you'd use `regex:/[\d]{1,2},[\d]{1,2}/`.

Comment: Thanks, really appriciete it. Have a lovley weekend :)

Comment: I have a question how will temperature be validated ? It could be both integer and decimal, but not a text.

Comment: @JasonLewis We don't need the square brackets `[\d]` do we.Can't we simply `\d`?